# Load a script when I press Space

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var s;
var scl = 20;
var food;
var audio = new Audio("background.mp3");
var audioDeath = new Audio("death.wav");
var audioEat = new Audio("ding.wav");
var img = new Image("imagine.png");

function setup() {
  audio.volume = 0.1;
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(10);
  input(start);
}

function start() {
  audio.play();
  s = new Snake();
  pickLocation();

}

function pickLocation() {
  var cols = floor(width / scl);
  var rows = floor(height / scl);
  food = createVector(floor(random(cols)), floor(random(rows)));
  food.mult(scl);
}

function draw() {
  background('black');
  if (s.eat(food)) {
    audioEat.pause();
    audioEat.currentTime = 0;
    audioEat.play();
    pickLocation();
    if ((food.x == s.x && food.y == s.y) || (s.tail.indexOf(food) > -1)) {
      pickLocation();
    }

  }
  if (s.death() == true) {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audioDeath.volume = 0.5;
    audioDeath.play();
    start();
  }
  s.update();
  s.show();



  fill(255, 0, 100);
  rect(food.x, food.y, scl, scl);
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW && s.yspeed != 1) {
    s.dir(0, -1);
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW && s.yspeed != -1) {
    s.dir(0, 1);
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW && s.xspeed != -1) {
    s.dir(1, 0);
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW && s.xspeed != 1) {
    s.dir(-1, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> SNAKE GAME</title>
  <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="snake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="imagine.png"></img>
</body>

</html>
```

So basicaly I've wanted to try out Javascript today and, with some help from some tutorials managed to code the game Snake. The only problem I have is the script runs right after the page loaded where I would like it to run only after the user presses the space bar. I've been looking online for a few hours now but still can't manage to do it.

Comment: You need to show the code you have so far.

Comment: Wrap the entirety of your code in a function called `startGame();` and then create a keypress event for spacebar that executes the function... You're not gonna get much more help without some code, as Paul points out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener like this

```js
var main = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
window.addEventListener("keypress", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32)
    main.style.background = "red";
  
}
```

```css
.main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
Press Space
</div>
```